# Voter registration fraud: how is citizenship checked?

Tags: united-states, citizenship, election-fraud, voter-registration

This question is motivated by the recent discussions about "voter fraud" and "rigged election" in the media. I am not asking about the extent of actual voter fraud, but about how easy it would be to commit fraud.
There are many potential types of fraud, but let me focus on one:
suppose you're not a US citizen, and wish to register and cast a vote at a presidential election (illegally of course). How easy would it be to do that?

I have tried to answer the question myself, and of course the answer will depend on the state. Let me consider for instance Massachusetts, which is the state where I live, and should be a good representative of the states that do not have law considered as limiting votes by putting excessive requirements. To vote in Massachussets, you must be registered, which
can be done in three ways: online, by mail, in person. By mail seems the easiest way, because you need to give your name and address, and either a copy of a government ID, or the last four digits of your SSN, or any lease, bill, etc with your name and address or it. I was surprised that there it is not required to give a document showing that you are indeed a citizen.
Hence my question:

> Does the state (MA for instance, or any other you may have information on) try to check if you're a citizen when you register for voting? If so, how?

This can be split into many subquestions. Does the state check if the four digits of the SSN you give matches the name you give? Assuming it does,
can the state check if a person, known to it by name and SSN, is a citizen or not? If yes, how? Is there a federal registry  of all citizens, that the individual states can access to? What if instead of giving your last four number of SSN, you just give a document with your name or address (which seems trivial to fake). Will the state check if the person trying to register exists, and if this person is a citizen? How?

[I am French, and a permanent resident in the US. I am a little bit surprised about how these things are organized are, because the rule in France is that when you ask for something reserved to citizen (registering for voting, getting a passport, etc.) you yourself have to provide the proof that you are indeed a citizen, by furnishing either a birth certificate showing that you're born in France and that one of your parent was either French or born in France at the time you were born (that's the condition for being French by birth), or a naturalization document. There seems to be nothing of that sort in the US (in MA at least)...]

Comment: This would be hard to cover completely. You've asked several subquestions, and the answer to each will depend on the state, like you mentioned.

Comment: Is it true that you need to be a French citizen to vote in France? I'd understood EU citizens could vote in local and European elections across the EU...

Comment: While a valid question, it assumes this is an effective means of fraud...which it really isn't. In-person voter fraud is a really inefficient way to sway an election. All that said, I think you can easily find a lot of info on this topic by reading up on all the voter ID law debates going on at the moment.

Comment: Oh, but *in general* states that require registration to vote, typically require some form of proof of 'being who you say you are and live where you say you live'. What that proof is can vary.

Comment: @blip  This doesn't ask about in-person fraud--it's asking about **registration** fraud.  Once registered, they can cheat the normal way:  by absentee ballot.  Note for example the problems that some states are having with people claiming not to be citizens when called for jury duty but claiming to be citizens when voting.  Proving that you live in a certain place doesn't establish that you are eligible to vote there.  It's just one requirement.

Comment: @Orgimbo, yes that's right, I was thinking at presidential and legislative (that is for the *assemblée nationale*) elections mainly, the most important one. That said, being French, I am not sure how it works when you're a citizen of some country of the UE and want to register to vote in France for local or European elections, but very likely they require some proof of citizenship of the country you're a citizen of.

Comment: @blip "I think you can easily find a lot of info on this topic by reading up on all the voter ID law debates going on at the moment". I'd like to. If someone can hint where to look for, it would be helpful. Right now, even if the quality media (like NYT) I didn't see any explanation of how the whole system functions about voter registration, only fragments of the debate where one side accuses the other of being racist and the other accuses the former of being fraudsters.

Comment: @Geoblits I agree. But an explanation (or link pointing to an explanation) of how one state (any state, not necessarily MA) without a controversial "Voter ID law" works this out would be pretty satisfying for me...

Comment: @Brythan either way, it's a really inefficient way to sway an election...which is why the 'Rigged Election' rhetoric is so ridiculous.

Comment: @Joël well, but one example, in WA, if you have a driver's license, you can register to vote. There are other ways to register if you don't have a driver's license.

Comment: As a reminder, comments are for clarifying the question.

Comment: Related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/3072/115. Tons of things that could answer your question were actually in comment threads

Comment: Thanks a lot user4012. The discussion was interesting. Perhaps I missed something, but it doesn't seem to answer my question though. It is a discussion about the actuality of fraud, not about what the states (without voter ID laws, or with them) routinely do to prevent it..

Comment: Short answer, Mass doesn't check if you just provide a utility bill.  You would be home free.

Comment: It's funny that registering is so easy, yet 40% don't bother to show up to vote.

Comment: Getting a passport (and other government things that require citizenship) require documentary proof.  Voting is special - there's a conscientious decision that it's more important to make sure no one is kept from voting than it is to make sure that possibly fraudulent voters are restricted.  A lot of this is tied to the nasty history of the country (slavery, Jim Crow, the reconstruction amendments to the constitution and the 24th amendment).  US History includes *many* severe restrictions on voting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is anything preventing non-US citizens from illegally registering to vote in non-Voter-ID states?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/29879/is-anything-preventing-non-us-citizens-from-illegally-registering-to-vote-in-non)  Which is not to say that this is not an eloquently expressed or an uninteresting question.  But it is effectively the same as the duplicate and some of the answer to that one may illuminate anyone seeking an answer to this Q as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Say you register successfully in Massachusetts through your water bill. After that you basically have nothing to worry about. The only states that are actively checking the Social Security Network are Virginia, Nevada, and Washington [NCSL](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/voter-list-accuracy.aspx)
The only checks that are legal and would occur are the following, none of which is likely to occur.

> A state may remove the name of a voter from the voter list under the following circumstances:
> A voter confirms in writing that he/she moved from the jurisdiction or wishes to be removed from the voter rolls. To do this a voter could: make the request directly in writing; complete a confirmation card confirming a change of address; or complete a voter registration application in a different jurisdiction and provide information about the prior registration, which can be treated as a request to cancel/transfer the prior registration.
>
> The state receives reliable second-hand information that the voter has moved (through the United States Postal Service, for example) AND the voter doesn’t respond to a confirmation mailing sent by the state AND the voter fails to vote or appear to vote between the time the confirmation mailing was sent and the second federal general election.
>
> The state receives reliable information that a voter is deceased.
>
> Depending on state regulations, voters can be removed for mental incapacity or a criminal conviction (see NCSL’s Felon Voting Rights page for information on the varied state requirements for persons with felony convictions to regain voting rights).

Given the above, it's not surprising that 1000s of illegal immigrants are on the voter registration [rolls](http://www.thepoliticalinsider.com/virginia-voter-fraud-thousands-illegal-aliens-registered-vote/)

Comment: It's worth noting that someone's being on the social security rolls does not necessarily mean that the person is a US citizen.

Comment: "it's not surprising that 1000s of illegal immigrants are on the voter registration rolls" That's a highly unreliable website, and nothing in the article supports that there are any "illegal immigrants" on the voter rolls. It says "1,046 non-alien citizens were registered to vote" -- of course citizens are non-aliens, and it's normal for them to be registered to vote. The linked-to study says "1,046 alien non-citizens successfully registered to vote"; nothing there says they are "illegal" aliens. Indeed, illegal aliens cannot get driver's licenses in Virginia, so they must be legal aliens.

Comment: @user102008: It also has nothing to do with why illegal aliens are on the rolls. It has to do with why some citizens are on the rolls two or more times.

Comment: " The only checks that are legal and would occur are the following, none of which is likely to occur." No cite given. "Given the above, it's not surprising that 1000s of illegal immigrants are on the voter registration rolls" No cite given.

Comment: @phoog The Social Security Administration keeps a record of whether or not the person with the social security number is or isn't a citizen.  At naturalization ceremonies, new citizens are reminded to update their status with the Social Security Administration.   "visit Social Security so they can update your Social Security record. Wait at least 10 days after your ceremony ... show them your Certificate of Naturalization or your U.S. passport." https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Office%20of%20Citizenship/Citizenship%20Resource%20Center%20Site/Publications/PDFs/M-767.pdf

Comment: @DavePhD That may be, but it's not clear to me whether the SSA makes citizenship status of its registrants available to state election authorities.  Besides, there's generally no need to update the Social Security record.  Permanent residents are equally authorized to work in the US and equally eligible for social security benefits.

Comment: @phoog maybe for federal aid http://ask.usc.edu/app/answers/detail/a_id/111/~/i-received-notification-that-my-u.s.-citizenship-has-not-been-confirmed-on-my or federal jobs that require citizenship, it should be updated

Comment: @DavePhD I suspect that federal jobs requiring US citizenship require the applicant to show a document evidencing US citizenship rather than relying on SSA records. (Don't most of those jobs require citizenship indirectly because citizenship is a requirement for security clearance?)  As for financial aid, that does seem to be a legitimate concern, but obviously affects only some people. But to get back on topic, my point is that AFAIK there is no way for states to check a person's citizenship status with the SSA. One could be created, of course, but that seems not to have happened.

Comment: @phoog it's not just for clearances.  "In general, you must be a U.S. citizen or national (residents of American Samoa and Swains Island) to work for the Federal Government" https://www.usajobs.gov/Help/working-in-government/non-citizens/ This says that e-verify has a database of citizenship status https://www.usajobs.gov/Help/working-in-government/us-citizens/

Comment: (-1 for using highly biased anti-immigrant data; link now dead) The claim that there are thousands or millions of illegal aliens on the voter rolls is very shaky. In some cases, people were incorrectly added to the rolls through clerical error at their Department of Motor Vehicles. The particular Virginia examination was junk; for example, no effort was made to see if non-citizens had become citizens, or if citizens had been incorrectly listed as non-citizens on the matching data rather than vice versa.

Comment: @DavePhD in general, perhaps, but if you read that first link you'll see that federal jobs outside the competitive civil service are as open to green card holders as they are to US nationals.  And e-verify may or may not have a database of citizenship status. It verifies that the subject of the inquiry is authorized to work in the US, which includes permanent residents and nonimmigrant workers. Since employers using e-verify have to have to see a document showing the legal basis of the right to work, the system does not need access to SSA's data on the subject's citizenship.

Comment: @DavePhD regardless, none of that is particularly relevant to how (or even whether) states might query SSA data to assess voter eligibility.

Comment: "Say you register successfully in Massachusetts through your water bill." This isn't sufficient to register in Massachusetts. You must provide your driver's license number or social security number to register to vote.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a naturalized US Citizen (originally Canadian).  As far as I know, there are three, maybe four, governmental organizations that know that I'm a US citizen:

1. The United States Citizenship and Immigration Services.  They track me by an "A-number" (alien number) that no one else uses.  They don't really care about me anymore - I'm sure I still have a file there, but...
2. The Social Security Administration.  Right after you naturalize, you are advised to let the SSA know of your new status.  That's because the benefits for citizens are somewhat better than for folks like Permanent Residents.  I filled in a form and showed them a passport (or my naturalization certificate - I can't remember which) for proof.
3. The Department of State - I have a US Passport.  This is optional, though I suspect that just about everyone who naturalizes gets a passport.
4. Maybe the Texas drivers' license folks (it's now the DMV, but that's a new name).  When you get a driver's license you need to show citizenship or immigration status (for "Real ID" purposes).  The thing is, I was a permanent resident when I got my first Texas driver's license.  I don't think I've ever showed them my US passport.

Looking at the standard Texas voter registration application (https://webservices.sos.state.tx.us/vrapp/index.asp), it asks if you are citizen and then asks for the last four digits of your SSN or for your full driver's license number.  With a name and a 4-digit SSN, they can probably get your full SSN (or possibly a small list of probable entries).  From that, they might be able get your citizenship status.  I'd be surprised if they can ascertain your citizenship status from your driver's license number (maybe).

I do know that Texas counties will eventually drop you from the voter rolls.  My daughter moved out of state, and after three letters to them (from me) saying she didn't live in our house anymore (over a period of years), we eventually got a letter saying that they were dropping her from the rolls (of course, that was two months after she'd moved back to Texas).

Comment: "I don't think I've ever showed them my US passport": at some point you'll have to though, for a future renewal, won't you?  If Texas were actually verifying citizenship using SSN records, don't you think they would just ask for the entire number?

Comment: I've renewed it since I naturalized.  I don't remember if I had to prove my citizenship or residence.  When you get a new Drivers' License, you need to prove enough residence-ness to comply with RealID requirements (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_ID_Act).  When I got my first TX DL, I had permanent residence.  I naturalized about 4 years later and was required to renew in person 10 years after that first DL.  I think I brought a passport with me, but I'm not sure I showed it.  I wasn't keeping good enough notes.

Comment: Very few organizations ask for a full SSN anymore.  There's great fear of leaking PII (Personally Identifiable Information), so they collect the last four digits instead.  The thing is, with a full name and the last four of an SSN, most systems can identify a person.

Comment: But most systems use the last four digits of the SSN in combination with other data to help with *internal* identification of people.  More commonly, as with banks, they use it for authentication: they already know the whole SSN, and they can be reasonably sure that anyone who knows the last four digits also knows the whole SSN.  But any organization that needs to identify someone in the Social Security Administration's actual records asks for the entire number.

Comment: As to DL renewals, my understanding is that for citizens (and I suppose also for permanent residents) every other renewal requires in-person proof of lawful presence; alternate renewals can be by mail.  If you had to renew in person, I suppose it's because you had to prove lawful presence, in which case you probably did show your passport.  But my understanding is derived by inference from DMV sites of a small number of states rather than directly from having read the Real ID act.  My state allows people to get non-Real-ID licenses, so I did that.

Comment: @phoog: There are services that will allow you to identify someone from Name + SSN-last4 (and some other combinations of "personal identifiable information").  I used to work at one of the major Credit Bureaus (one of Equifax/Experian/etc).  They sell services to companies (restricted to those that have a "permissible purpose") that will help you do that.  I believe that those subscribers include the government (I'm pretty sure that Equifax supplies identification software for the e-Verify system - or did, the last time I used it)

Comment: I think the answer is missing a vital issue. It is very easy to walk up on the street and hit a random person and run away, but if you get caught there is a punishment, so why would you do that. And the same with voter fraud, the punishment if you get caught is enough to stop people.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle: I completely agree.  The _benefits_ from a single person voting illegally are very small (you'd need to have a lot of folks follow your lead to have any effect), but the _costs_ of doing that (the potential punishment if you are caught) is quite high

Comment: @Flydog57 The difference between voting illegally and hitting a random person on the street is that, if you hit a random person on the street, you are easily found.  The person who you hit has incentive to go to the cops and say, "I was just hit on the street by a person who looked like XYZ", and the cops will get to searching.  However, with illegal voting, how does anyone even know that illegal voting took place?  Firstly a complaint has to be made.  Then that complaint has to go through levels of validation and verification to get acted on, then someone has to go through reams of data to...

Comment: ...verify, and even then, as OP stated, the legal methods for getting a ballot do not correspond with certainty of citizenship, so even after you have all the data, you may still not even have your answer.  The probability of being caught is unbelievably small.  Conversely, to some people (myself included), voting is not seen as a way to "have an effect".  Voting is something you do, because you want your voice to be heard, however small your voice might be.  So your assertion that the benefits are very small and the costs are very high, in addition to being spurious, is also irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

Washington State does not check citizenship status. The Republican Sec State has tried to get legislation through the state legislature to enable the state to do this, but has been unable to get it passed. In WA, you can register to vote with a driver's license, but that license requires no citizenship check, so it follows that non-citizens can register to vote, actually vote, and have their vote counted.  Without the ability to check the citizenship status of a particular voter, it would be nigh on impossible to provide evidence of fraud.

"There's no evidence" is a refrain we've heard often the past few months. Two points:

- Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence
- If you don't have the ability to unearth evidence, you can't logically expect there to be any.

In my mind, any election that takes place without checking for citizenship status is illegitimate.  It is the most basic of checks that must be in place to ensure the election has integrity.  The US and the UK are the only two industrialized democracies that do not check for citizenship / have voter ID laws.

WA State voter registration form: https://www.sos.wa.gov/_assets/elections/vrf_print_2020_english.pdf

WA State driver license identity verification requirements: https://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/idproof.html (Note that an SSN does not prove citizenship, and if you don't have an SSN, you can still get a license.)

Proving citizenship is not required for a WA driver license: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-undocumented-person-washington-drivers-license.html

WA Sec State pushing for citizenship check: https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/politics/proposal-would-allow-citizenship-check-for-voter-registration-in-washington/

Comment: The four people who have voted down (so far) this answer from a new contributor without explaining what they think is wrong with it has just shown the narrowness of their own mind. I have not verified the assertion that in WA you can register with only a driver-license, but as an immigrant non-citizen with a perfectly valid driver license, I know that you can get one legally without being a citizen, as the contributor states.